# Can we have different column type based on value of the same model data

Tags: sapui5

I am displaying data in the table using sap.m.table. The table is created in the controller using java script.  JSON model is binded to the table. In one of the column of the table, if there is no value i have to provide a button in the same column, for the user to click and create data .

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using an aggregation binding using a [Factory Function](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/28/4a036c8ff943238fb65bf5a2676fb7/content.htm?no_cache=true)

Factory function is used to generate different controls based on the data received at runtime

```
onCreateTable: function () {
    var oData = {
        "items": [
          {  "Column1": "Col1", "Column2": "Col12", "value": "10" },
          {  "Column1": "Col2", "Column2": "Col22", "value": "9" },
          {  "Column1": "Col3", "Column2": "Col32", "value": "7" },
          {  "Column1": "Col4", "Column2": "Col52", "value": "1" },
          {  "Column1": "Col6", "Column2": "Col62", "value": "3" },
          {  "Column1": "Col7", "Column2": "Col72", "value": "" }              
       ]};

    var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
        headerToolbar: new sap.m.Toolbar({
            content: [new sap.m.Label({
                text: ""
            })]
        }),
        columns: [new sap.m.Column({
            width: "2em",
            header: new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Column1"
            })
        }), new sap.m.Column({
            width: "2em",
            header: new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Column2"
            })
        }), new sap.m.Column({
            width: "2em",
            header: new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Column3"
            })
        })]
    });
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("tableWrapper").addItem(oTable);

    oTable.bindItems({
        path: "/items",
        factory: this.populateItems.bind(this)
    });
    oTable.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData));
},    
populateItems: function(sId, oContext) {
    var oInput = null;
    if(oContext.getObject().value)
        oInput = new sap.m.Label({ text: oContext.getObject().value });
    else
        oInput = new sap.m.Button({ text: "Create" });

    var oRow = new sap.m.ColumnListItem(sId, {
        type: "Active",
        cells: [
           new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Column1}" }),
           new sap.m.Text({ text: "{Column2}" }),
           oInput
        ]
    });
    return oRow;
},
```

Output

[image]